# How to fix @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises error

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a onClick() method for a PrimaryButton class. I got @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises error from eslint check. Code as below:

```
onClick = { () =>
    Utils.getName(a, b).then(
        (name) => {
            Utils.deleteThing(name, x, y);
        })
    }
```

How should I fix my code to avoid this error? Would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Update: eslint config as follows
[image]

Error message is on the line of onClick():
[image]

Comment: Can you show your ESLint configuration? And on which line does the error occur exactly? What is the error message?

Comment: Hi, please refer to my updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states that a void return was expected. But instead, you are returning a promise.

```
onClick = { () =>
    Utils.getName(a, b).then(
        (name) => {
            Utils.deleteThing(name, x, y);
        })
    }
```

The way you write your arrow function, you are returning the below code (a promise) rather than running it and just returning nothing:

```
Utils.getName(a, b).then(
            (name) => {
                Utils.deleteThing(name, x, y);
            })
```

However, if you write your code like this, void is returned and the code is actually ran:

```
onClick = { () => {
    Utils.getName(a, b).then(
        (name) => {
            Utils.deleteThing(name, x, y);
        })
    }
}
```

The key is how an arrow function works. If you leave out the `{` `}` after the `=>`, the return is implied to be the single statement after the `=>` which is not what you wanted. You didn't want to return the `Utils.getName` function, you just wanted it to run. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#description) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. There should be a {} after the arrow. And there is another eslint issue. It enforces a catch() to follow the then(). After I modified to this, there is no build error.
onClick = { () => {
    Utils.getName(a, b).then(
        (name) => {
            Utils.deleteThing(name, x, y);
        }).catch(() => {});
    }
}

Comment: @Tony An empty catch statement (more than) defeats the purpose of that rule. The required catch statement is there so that you're forcing yourself to define the catch handler. Not to just put in an empty catch handler that will eat your errors.

Comment: I would put corresponding error handling logic for catch() section. It would not be empty. I was just explaining the eslint issue.

Comment: The before and after code are exactly the same making this answer very confusing

Comment: @MichaelDurrant no the two are not the same. One has a a ‘{‘ after the ‘=>’ and the other does not. As I wrote in the text, this changes the return value versus actually running the code. It is a very nuanced, but impactful, difference.